# PC Queue using TPL?

Tags: .net, queue, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow, blockingcollection

### Original

How would I create a Producer-Consumer Queue in C# leveraging the TPL and/or Concurrent Collections? I'm using .NET 4.5+.

Here's my first attempt:

```
public class SampleFileProcessor
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _queue = 
        new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Imagine this method is inside a WCF service and gets called from
        // thousands of different clients, and very frequently from each one.
        // This doesn't feel like correct design. I'm firing off a separate 
        // threadpool task to process a single item every time?
        // Is the TPL smart enough to re-use an existing thread that is already 
        // running the ConsumeQueue() method? Is this efficient?

        _queue.Add(fileName);         
        Task.Run(() => ConsumeQueue());
    }

    private void ConsumeQueue()
    {
        foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // fake a time-consuming process.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit Sep 5,2014: Version 2 based on feedback.

```
public class SampleFileProcessor
{
    private int _count;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _queue =
        new BlockingCollection<string>();        

    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        _queue.Add(fileName);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        Task.Run(() => ConsumeQueue());
    }

    private void ConsumeQueue()
    {
        while (_count > 0)
        {
            string item = null;
            if (_queue.TryTake(out item, 1000))
            {
                // fake a time-consuming process.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit Sep 7,2014: Problem solved.

I discovered the [`Microsoft Task Parallel Library Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) classes which already encapsulate exactly what I want and much more.
NuGet package: `Install-Package Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow`

To benefit the community, I'll share some test code.
(Also at https://dotnetfiddle.net/WbwUqz)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace TPLDataFlowTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            // Task Parallel Library Dataflow:
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx
            // Install-Package Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow

            // Other resources on the web:
            // http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephen-Toub-Inside-TPL-Dataflow
            // http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=tpldataflow

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBasicPCQueue =>");
            tasks.Add(TestBasicPCQueue());

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nBatchingPCQueue =>");
            tasks.Add(TestBatchingPCQueue());

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nPress Enter to quit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static Task TestBasicPCQueue()
        {
            var action = new ActionBlock<string>(
                async s =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}...", s);
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);
                },
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }
            );

            Parallel.For(0, 5,
                i =>
                {
                    string item = "BasicPCQ " + i;
                    action.Post(item);
                    Console.WriteLine("BasicPCQ posted " + i);
                }
            );

            action.Complete();
            return action.Completion;
        }

        public static Task TestBatchingPCQueue()
        {
            int count = 5;
            int remaining = count;
            var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            var pcq = new PCQueue<string>(
                action: array =>
                {
                    var s = string.Join(",", array);
                    Console.WriteLine("PCQ [{0}] waiting 2000 ms ...", s);
                    Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
                    Console.WriteLine("PCQ [{0}] done", s);
                    remaining -= array.Length;
                    if (remaining == 0)
                    {
                        taskSource.SetResult(true);
                    }
                },
                batchSize: 2,
                maxDegreeOfParallism: 1,
                batchFlushAfterMilliseconds: 3000);

            Parallel.For(0, count, i =>
            {
                pcq.Add(i.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("PCQ posted " + i);
            });

            return taskSource.Task;
        }

    }

    public class PCQueue<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly BatchBlock<T> _batchBlock;
        private readonly ActionBlock<T[]> _actionBlock;
        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _batchTriggerTimer;
        private int _count;

        public PCQueue(Action<T[]> action, int batchSize, int maxDegreeOfParallism, double batchFlushAfterMilliseconds)
        {
            _batchBlock = new BatchBlock<T>(batchSize);
            _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<T[]>(
                array =>
                {
                    _batchTriggerTimer.Enabled = false;
                    action(array);
                    Interlocked.Add(ref _count, -array.Length); // decrement _count.
                    _batchTriggerTimer.Enabled = (_count > 0 && _count < _batchBlock.BatchSize);
                },
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallism }
            );

            _batchBlock.LinkTo(_actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

            // This is a watchdog timer to flush the batchBlock periodically if the 
            // number of items in the batch are below the threshold for 
            // auto-triggering. I wish this were built into the BatchBlock class.
            _batchTriggerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(batchFlushAfterMilliseconds);
            _batchTriggerTimer.Elapsed += delegate
            {
                _batchTriggerTimer.Enabled = false;
                _batchBlock.TriggerBatch();
            };
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            _batchBlock.Post(item);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
            _batchTriggerTimer.Enabled = (_count > 0 && _count < _batchBlock.BatchSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-voters, please explain why my question is so bad so that I can improve it.

Comment: What is `int count = 5;`? concurrent size? By the way, I just up-voted it. It's unfair to down vote it.

Comment: @Love, thank your for up-voting! `int count = 5` is just an arbitrary number of items that I throw into the PCQueue for testing.  I could have made it a const and assigned it any value.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't start a consumer after every `Add`. instead, start one or more (as efficiency demands for your case) long running consumers (note that your consumers `foreach` won't finish until you end the collection via `CompleteAdding`, **not** when the `BlockingCollection` is temporarily empty.).
Then, just `Add` in the producer.

Comment: Good catch regarding the foreach not ending! :) Let me experiment a bit.

Comment: @LeeGrissom, you haven't addressed the part re single consumer task or thread (or any other well-defined, finite number of parallel consumers), which was a good suggestion. Those consumers will be running indefinitely until each consumer's `foreach` exits due to `CompleteAdding` having been called on the `BlockingCollection`. A quick way to achieve that would be using your first implementation but moving `Task.Run(() => ConsumeQueue());` to the constructor rather than spawning one task per `ProcessFile` call.

Comment: Just to clarify why having `ConsumeQueue` called once per `ProcessFile` is a bad idea (in first code sample): you're spawning an ever-growing number of parallel tasks which will *all* stay alive until `BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding` is called and compete for the same work items returned by iterating through `GetConsumingEnumerable`. Each item will still only be processed by a single task (whichever one snatches it first), but the thread synchronisation involved in that, not to mention thread pool saturation due to the number of active parallel tasks, will be through the roof.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, I don't think I will have an ever growing list of tasks. I corrected this problem in my version 2 code. The while loop in `ConsumeQueue` will exit when `_count` goes to zero. There is not a need for me to call `CompleteAdding`. I verified this assumption earlier this evening in a test harness. I will research in the morning whether the TPL will be smart enough to handle an infinite number of calls to Task.Run().

Comment: @LeeGrissom, make your test harness call `ProcessFiles` in a tight loop. That 1000ms delay inside the `foreach` consumer loop, coupled with a 1000ms timeout on `TryTake`, is enough time to queue up a very large number of tasks, a lot of which won't ever get to execute any actual work (because another task will have stolen the work item designated for the newly spun task). These redundant tasks will just block until `TryTake` times out, causing scalability problems without bringing anything useful to the table. This is one of those problems which are awfully hard to solve in a lock-free manner.

Comment: now you're perverting the mechanism just so you are able to spin up a huge number of short lived threads. that is a completely unneccesary overhead; starting threads is expensive (and so is anyhing interlocked)

Comment: oh, and if you really want to start a Task for each item, why use a collection at all? just start your processor in a thread with the item as argument. of course, that's no producer/consumer pattern anymore.

Comment: I discovered the [Microsoft TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) classes... and those are exactly what I should use to solve this problem.